# Catch fatal errors in PHP in whole app by surrounding code with try/catch?

Tags: php, error-handling, try-catch

Now that we can [catch fatal errors in PHP7](https://trowski.com/2015/06/24/throwable-exceptions-and-errors-in-php7/) ([set_error_handler cannot](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php#:%7E:text=The%20following%20error%20types%20cannot%20be%20handled%20with%20a%20user%20defined%20function%3A%20E_ERROR%2C%20E_PARSE%2C%20E_CORE_ERROR%2C%20E_CORE_WARNING%2C%20E_COMPILE_ERROR%2C%20E_COMPILE_WARNING%20independent%20of%20where%20they%20were%20raised%2C%20and%20most%20of%20E_STRICT%20raised%20in%20the%20file%20where%20set_error_handler()%20is%20called.)), would it be a good idea to use it to catch errors on a whole project? Mine is always going through index.php, so I was planning to do this:

```
try {
    //All the code and includes, etc.
} catch(Error $ignored) {
    //save the error in log and/or send a notification to admin.
}
```

I tried first to be sure:

```
set_error_handler(function(int $number, string $message) {
    echo "Error $number: '$message'" . PHP_EOL  ;
 });

$var = $undeclared_var     //The error is sent to the error_handler.

function_dont_exist(); //The error isn't sent to the error_handler.
```

```
try {
    function_dont_exist();
}
catch(Error $E){
    echo "Error";     //That works.
}
```

Is it a good idea / good practice to envelope the whole code with a try/catch/error to deal with them? It sounds good, but I wonder why I don't see it much. I tried and I believe it works, but it sounds too easy.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well just to get the error logged, you wouldn't need to catch it yourself, a default mechanism for logging errors already exists ...

Comment: @CBroe You are right. But in my app, I want to log more info than what is done by the default mechanism (i.e. included files, function calls, post and get request, etc.).